circular dependency between yum-utils and yum-config-manager
I'm trying to build a docker image in a corporate environment.
RUN yum-config-manager --nogpgcheck --add-repo http://repo.mycompany.com/rhel8-x86_64/latest/RPMS.all && \
yum-config-manager --nogpgcheck --add-repo http://repo.mycompany.com/rhel-8-server-rpms/ && \
yum -y install --nogpgcheck yum-utils wget

This fails with:
/bin/sh: yum-config-manager: command not found

A quick google indicates that yum-config-manager is packaged inside yum-utils.
If I add a yum install yum-utils command before the code above, I get:
Error: Unable to find a match: yum-utils

So I can't download yum-utils without first adding the repo, using yum-config-manager.  But I can't run yum-config-manager until I've installed yum-utils.
How can I get around this?

You can try adding the repo of your company manually. Add a new file named /etc/yum.repos.d/mycompany.repo
Add the following entry to that file.
[mycompany]
name=MyCompany Repo
baseurl=http://repo.mycompany.com/rhel8-x86_64/latest/RPMS.all
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

After that, run yum clean all && yum update. If you are able to use the first repo, add another repo entry in the same file in another block. It should work.
Ref: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/add-yum-repository
In the reference, they've verified the manual entry using yum-config-manager. Since it is not preinstalled in Docker container, just skip the verification part.
If you face any issue while running this solution, feel free to paste the errors. To revert back, simply delete /etc/yum.repos.d/mycompany.repo file and run yum clean all && yum update.
